# R add text string to plot and align columns

Tags: r, plot, text, alignment

I am trying to add a text string to a plot with the first column left justified and the second column right justified. For example:

```
vegetables: -123.4567
minerals:  45631.7840
plants:        0.0797
animals:     -89.7500
```

Here is the code I've devised, which will work for the first column, but not the 2nd column.

```
plot(1,1, xlim=c(-2,2), ylim=c(-2,2))
text(0,0, paste(
"\nvegetables:", formatC(-123.4567, digits=4, format="f"),
"\nminerals:",   formatC(45631.784, digits=4, format="f"),
"\nplants:",     formatC(0.0797, digits=4, format="f"),
"\nanimals:",    formatC(-89.75, digits=4, format="f"),
sep=""),
pos=4)
```

Comment: Do you mean table instead of plot?

Comment: Hello ssp3nc3r,

I do mean plot, not table.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried coding some kind of plot to, I assume, overlay the above text (as a table)? There isn't much guidance in your question on either what you have tried, or precisely what you want.

Comment: I have added the plot line to the script for clarity.
I want the text that is added to be aligned and justified as shown in my example.